# Between Passenger and Rails, url-encoded underscores in urls aren't being handled properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a Rails app deployed to my server under the context `scala_tour`.  When going to the URL, everything works great.  However, if the url is encoded to `scala%5ftour` (which is what SO does, incidentally), I get an error from Rails and/or Passenger.

Passenger seems to recognize the URL and  hands it off to my Rails app, but the Rails app complains with:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/scala%5Ftour" with {:method=>:get}):
```

Which is quite odd.

Other than putting in a redirect in Apache and deploying my app to a different context, how can I deal with this?

### Versions

```
# yum list installed | grep http
httpd.i386                               2.2.10-2.el5.eapps     installed    
# yum list installed | grep passen
passenger.i386                           2.2.2-1eapps           installed 
# gem list | grep rails
rails (2.3.2, 2.2.2)
# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-06-20 patchlevel 230) [i386-linux]
```

### routes.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :wiki_pages do |wiki_map|
    wiki_map.history 'history', :controller => 'wiki_pages', :action => 'history', :method => 'GET'
    wiki_map.version 'version/:sha1', :controller => 'wiki_pages', :action => 'version', :method => 'GET'
  end
  map.history '/history.:format', :controller => 'wiki_pages', :action => 'wiki_history', :method => 'get'
  map.resources :diagrams, :only => [:index,:new,:destroy,:edit,:show]
  map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy' 
  map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
  map.resources :users
  map.resource :session
  map.root :controller => 'wiki_pages', :action => 'show', :id => 'MainPage'
end
```

### Apache conf

```
RailsBaseURI /scala_tour
PassengerPoolIdleTime 5
```

Comment: Can you tell us what version of Passenger and Apache you are using? I'm unable to reproduce this problem with Passenger 2.5.5 and Apache 2.2.9.

Comment: What is "SO"?  I don't think translating %5f to _ is expected behavior for a controller or action name.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes.rb, please?

Comment: Oh and the passenger-specific block in your apache config while we are at it?

Comment: Hi, more questions: Did you set "config.action_controller.relative_url_root" in the "enviroment.rb"? If so which value did you set? Have you tried both "scala_tour" and "scala%5ftour"? I would also like to know which version of rails your app is currently running on as you have two installed and I found some threads on the internet concerning routing with a subdirectory and rails 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Two things come immediately to mind you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in apache to normalize the URL or you could use Rack Middleware to rewrite it. [Here](http://github.com/joshbuddy/rack-rewrite) is a gem that would probably do the trick for you.

Comment: Currently, I re-rooted the app to `scalatour` and have apache rewriting the url `scala_tour` to `scalatour`.  Seems odd that it shouldn't just work, tho.  I mean, from a URL perspective, `scala_tour` and `scala%5Ftour` should be the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Just ran into this issue the other day in IE/Safari: http://wantnotechno.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/ie-gotcha-1-uri-underscores/. Apparently underscores in a URI has some issues due to legacy specs for older browsers.

Comment: It was in Firefox and Safari on Mac